# Self Balancing AVL Tree with low memory usage?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

A Self Balancing AVL Tree is usually implemented with a list. Each node contains:

```
pointer to parent (8 bytes on 64 bit apps)
pointer to left child (8 bytes on 64 bit apps)
pointer to right child (8 bytes on 64 bit apps)
balance (4 bytes)

pointer to the data struct (8 bytes on 64 bit apps)
```

Because the data are aligned in memory we need `40 bytes` per item.

In my application I need **a)** extremely fast lookup, **b)** very fast insert and **c)** low memory usage.

**Q**: Is it possible to reduce the memory usage of the Self Balancing AVL Tree data structure?

Comment: ditch the pointer the parent.

Comment: I am learning how SO works and I don't understand why my question is downvoted, can someone please explain?

Comment: @StoryTeller: What I lose if I do that?

Comment: Your Q2 is out of order for SO. It asks for people to do your work for you. Either actual coding or research.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Thanks

Comment: You don't really need a pointer to the parent, you *do* however need a pointer to the next sibling in the list.

Comment: To get meaningful answers, you'd need to show why you're making the claims you do. There are excellent AVL tree libraries in open source (see e.g. http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/avl) that will show you balance only needs 2 bits (libraries usually use 1 byte). No parent pointer is necessary. Additionally, it seems to be a consensus opinion that red-black trees are simpler and have slightly higher average performance (avl lookups are a bit faster, but insertion/deletion is slower, and these dominate in many applications). E.g. java libs use red-black trees in sources I've looked at.

Comment: @Gene: Thanks for the library

Comment: If you don't need to delete nodes (except at the end when you delete all of them), you can keep all the nodes in an array (or a C++ `std::vector<avl_node>`, to get convenient append of new nodes with realloc when needed).  Then your pointer fields only need to hold an array index, which can be 16 or 32 bits.  Alternatively, if you can do memory allocation in the low 4GB, they can be real pointers but still only 4B.  (The Linux x32 ABI works this way: CPU in 64bit mode, register-call ABI, but pointers are 32b.  https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/x32)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has similar project and I did similar aesearch to yours.

My answer is based on pure technical side, no to the AVL algorithm.

You can try pack the struct/class. Despate what everyone say, this will not hurt performance on x86 machines.

Edit:
you definitely need to remove pointer to the parent. Instead of top node, Wrap everything in a master class.

Then you probably be able to pack balance in 2 bytes, but it will reduce the overal size of the tree.

Then at some point you probably find that standard (linux) malloc allocate lots of additional space. This can be fixed with jemalloc. However, jemalloc performance is slower than standard malloc.

If you want, you can try google's tcmalloc. Its performance is bteer thanstandard malloc and  mem usage is on the middle between standard malloc andbjemalloc. However tcmalloc is considered beta or unstable.

I also will suggest If you can, store data directly inside your tree node, e.g. do not use pointer. This will save 8 bytes and one additional allocation.

As final node, please do check std::map and std::set - those are red black trees and working extremly well.

Please do check skip lists. I will add comment to my implementation later. My skip list have performance similar to std::map (bit slower, I can not do good comparisson), but memory usage is 20 - 30% better.

Comment: skiplist : https://github.com/nmmmnu/HM3/blob/master/skiplist.h. note this skiplist is bit specialized and can not be used without rewriting at least the part for compare / store pairs.